# Replace String With Number In List, Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, list

How can I replace '-infinity' with 0 number using a function in Google Earth Engine? I'm gonna to replace string with 0 value in the list automatically.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1bd2127a2d5f0994dfd593be190edd60

```
var x  = ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,'-infinity','-infinity']);

var y = ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);

print('xvalues',x);
print('yvalues',y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [replaceAll](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-replaceall):

x = x.replaceAll('-infinity', 0);

Comment: it is true but in the below link it doesn't work:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/181f7a30b44ecb7483d1a0e693f6fb0d

Comment: print('value estimated:',value.replace(ee.Number(0).log(),0)) can be used as a workaround